# Program crashes when I try to input values

Tags: c++, debugging

so I've got integers m and n in my program, once you input the values it should create an array with values from m to n (for example m = 1 and n = 10, it creates array q with values from 1 to 10). Then it looks in the array if there are any numbers that are equal to any two number summ that are squared (for example, in the array, number 5 is equal to 1 squared + 2 squared). The problem is when I try to input the first value it crashes, pretty sure the problem is in the function but can't seem to figure it out. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int squared (int a, int b, int q[]){


    while (a<=0 || b<=0){
        cout <<"You can't input an integer that is 0 or below: ";
        cin >>a;
        cin >>b;
        if (a>0 || b>0) break;
    }


    for (int p=0; p<b; p++){
        for (int i=a ; i<b; i++){
            q[p] = a;
        }
    }

    for (int z=0; z<b; z++){
        for (int x=0; x<b; x++){
            for (int c=0; c<b; c++){
                if (q[z] == (q[x] * q[x]) + (q[c] * q[c])){
                    int result= (q[x] * q[x]) + (q[c] * q[c]);
                    return result;

                }
            }
        }
    }



}

int main () {
    int m,n;
    int M[100];
    cout <<"Input integers m un n: ";
    cin >>m,n;
    cout <<squared(m,n,M);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin >>m,n;` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this in the debugger to find out where the error is happening? Also, can you define "crash"? What exactly goes wrong? Please see [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) on debugging small programs.

Comment: `cin >>m >> n;`

Comment: The nested loop in the first `for` loop is currently useless

Comment: Not related to your crash, but `(a>0 || b>0) break;` is redundant, and the `||` should be flipped to `&&` anyway

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it crashes because of this: `cin >>m,n;`, it should be `cin >> m >> n;`, else you use `n` uninitialized on the next line, thus getting undefined behaviour, e.g. crash.

What compiler are you using and with what flags, since this would trigger some warnings/errors at compile normally.

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> m, n;` is incorrect which inputs only m which can be interpreted as:

`(cin >> m), n;` which means: `cin, n;` to correct it:

`cin >> m >> n;`

`if(a > 0 || b > 0) break;` is redundant because you check for this condition twice: once in while condition second inside while loop thus checking for the same condition is redundant because while breaks automatically if the condition succeeds (a or b is equal or smaller than 0).

you passed an array without passing its size, you are lucky if you set the first element 1 the any second value is equal to the size of array eg:

```
m = 1; n = 10; then the size is ten which is correct.
```

what about:

```
m = 7; n = 10; // now is size 10? it's only 3
```

to correct it pass the size eg:

```
m = 4; n = 8;
int size = 8 - 4;
cout << Squared(m, n, M, size);
```

also:

```
for (int p = 0; p < b; p++)
{
    for (int i = a ; i < b; i++)
    {
        q[p] = a;
    }
}
```

you are assigning the same value `a` to all elements of array and iterating doing the same thing in the nested-loop!!! it's likely to write:

```
int x = 0; x = 0;
```

so the condition of result inside squared will never succeed because the same value is never equal to its square. `4 = 4 * 4` is never reached

here is what you search for:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// I only make squared search for the result not inputing m and n lik e in yours
int squared (int m, int n, int* M)
{
    int result;
    for(int i(0); i < n; i++)
        for(int j(0); j < n; j++)
            for(int k(0); k < n; k++)
                if( (M[i] == ( (M[j] * M[j]) + (M[k] * M[k]) )) && j != k) // here to avoid comparing with the same index
                {
                    cout << M[i] << " = (" << M[j] << "*" << M[j] << ") + (" << M[k] << "*" << M[k] << ")" << endl;
                    result = ( (M[j] * M[j]) + (M[k] * M[k]) );
                    cout << result << endl;
                    return result; // if success we return result
                }

    return -1; // otherwise we return -1 as a sign of error (no square yields in negative value)
}

int main () 
{
    int n, m, size;

    do
    {   
        cout <<"m: ";
        cin >> m;
        cout << "n: ";
        cin >> n;

        if(n <= 0 || m <= 0)
            cout <<"You can't input an integer that is 0 or below: ";
        // also it's very important to check whether n is greater than m or not because if m == n or m > n then size will be negative and as you  know no array has a negative nor 0 size
        if(m >= n)
            cout << "n must be greater than m!" << endl;
    }while (m <= 0 || n <= 0 || m >= n);

    size = n - m; // getting size of array assuming m can be any value
    int* M = new int[n - m]; // allocating dynamic array

    // inputting array as you asked
    for(int i(0), j = m; i < size; i++, j++)
        M[i] = j;

    // checking the values of array elements
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << M[i] << ", " ;
    cout << endl;

    // getting the result
    cout << squared(m, n, M) << endl;

    // cleaning
    delete[] M;

    return 0;
}
```